# Fazer uma query com laravel com a seguinte lógica

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, query

Olá amigos da comunidade. Preciso preencher um gráfico mas não consigo montar a query para receber os atributos, alguém poderia me ajudar? A query que preciso fazer é a seguinte.

```
select client.name, count(*) as Tickets 
from client, ticket 
where client.id = ticket.client_id 
group by client.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode tentar:

```
use DB;
...
$dados = DB::select('select client.name, count(*) as Tickets 
from client, ticket 
where client.id = ticket.client_id 
group by client.id');
```

Comment: Funcionou direitinho, valeu amigo :)

Comment: De nada @FelipePaetzold, ainda bem